# Django Require Particular Version of Python to be Used

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I edited my `settings.py` file to have the following at the very bottom:

```
[requires]
python_version="3.7"
```

When I run `python manage.py runserver`, I get the following error message:

> NameError: name 'requires' is not defined

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[requires]
python_version="3.7"
```

[belongs in your `Pipfile`](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile#examples-spec-v6), not in `settings.py`.